# For automating a desktop eCommerce site running on mobile device as a mobileweb app, is Playwright a reasonable choice?

Tags: mobile, ui-automation, browserstack, playwright-java

At our client, they have an eCommerce website made of node.js, vue.js etc., which implements their SAP (ERP) backed processes. Customers use both desktop and mobile devices to create orders.

`WorkSoft` tool is being used to automate purchase processes on the eCommerce website and the back end SAP. Few pilot Selenium scripts have been developed(Cons: longer time to write, difficult locators, difficult to execute clicks()) to automate the "same eCommerce website" on mobile devices using BrowserStack mobile(Android, iOS) device farm.

My question is "Since Appium may not be suitable as this is NOT a native mobile application but a `mobileweb app` how can I use the new technology on the block - **Playwright an alternative to Selenium?** Is it doable in the first place?"

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/playwright

This should help you achieve your use case.

Comment: @grandEL-dsouza
I looked in to your suggestion, it looks like it is possible.  Let me try. Thanks.